# Angular directive's link function won't manipulate DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm trying to access data from a service so I can manipulate an `ngRepeat`ed list with jQuery. I cannot get the `link` function to work. Based on what I've read, I would expect that in either

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'url.html',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      //jQuery to manipulate DOM here
    }
  };
});
```

or

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'url.html',
    compile: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      return {
        post: function() {
          //jQuery to manipulate DOM here
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But the elements are not on the page yet, so it does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this the exact code? Because you have merged the returned object (directive definition object) and the function brackets.

Comment: @GregL No, that was quickly pseudo'd up and had a ton of syntax errors. Sorry about that. Updated.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the link function and confirm debugger breaks there? Also, can you show the ng-repeat and the collection variable returned from the service?

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting one $digest phase. This will give enough time to the `ng-repeat` to render the DOM elements. You can use $timeout for that.

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
    $timeout(function() {
        //jQuery to manipulate DOM here
    });
}
```

### EDIT:

Check the example below. Here we have `my-dir` collecting all the elements created by the `ng-repeat`. There is a helper `mockup-box` inner directive that include `my-dir` parent directive controller and registers itself (*its element*) using its methods.

Then `my-dir` controller calls the invalidateChildren function which waits for the children directive to accumulate by delaying the `validateChildren` function execution.

In the `validateChildren` function we manipulate the DOM elements and we are sure that they'll be there because each one registers only when it's compiled. There is some dummy code in validateChildren function but you can place anything there.

There is another added benefit. We no longer depend on the ng-repeat nor does my-dir knows how the child elements will be created. They might even be "static" children. It also supports adding additional children. If the ng-repeat generates additional elements they'll again register in the parent controller and invoke the validateChildren function.

```js
angular.module('example', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mockupData = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
})

.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    controller: function($element, $timeout) {
      var ctrl = this;
      var childrenDirty = false;
      
      this.children = [];
      
      this.addChild = function(jqChild) {
        ctrl.children.push(jqChild);
        ctrl.invalidateChildren();
      };
      
      this.removeChild = function(jqChild) {
        var index = ctrl.children.indexOf(jqChild);

        if (index >= 0) {
          ctrl.children.splice(index, 1);
        }
      };
      
      this.invalidateChildren = function() {
        if (!childrenDirty) {
          childrenDirty = true;
          $timeout(ctrl.validateChildren);
        }
      };
      
      this.validateChildren = function() {
        childrenDirty = false;

        // Will be fire only once
        angular.forEach(ctrl.children, function(jqChild) {
          jqChild.html('value: "' + jqChild.html() + '"');
        }); 
      };
    },
    link: function() {
    }
  }
})

.directive('mockupBox', function() {
  return {
    require: '^myDir',
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, myDirCtrl) {
      myDirCtrl.addChild(iElement);
      
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        myDirCtrl.removeChild(iElement);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div my-dir>
    <div ng-repeat="data in mockupData" mockup-box>{{data}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Expected behavior

- `mockupData` value is ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
- `validateChildren` function edits the child elements content and adds "value:" in front.

The result from the code execution will be `value: "<letter>"` for every child element.

Comment: Is the idea that the `$timeout` will wait for the digest to cycle before it runs even without giving is a time?

Comment: Yes. That's the idea. It will wait for the current $digest phase to complete and will run a new one after that. The function you passed will be executed in this second $digest phase.

Comment: It is. You can add an additional $watch on the ng-repeat collection and then do a $timeout in the $watch body or you can try if it works with $timeout inside the $timeout.

Comment: Both approaches will be hacky and might stop working. If you can do it with a directive attached on every single element ng-repeat creates it will be a much cleaner "Angular friendly" solution.

Comment: `scope.$evalAsync(fn)` seems to be working pretty well actually. Have you used that before? Do you think it might be good for this scenario?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added another approach you can try. If $evalAsync does the job use it. It's pretty close to what $timeout does.